# Creating Camera view as overlay of another view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, camera

I have a QR code scanner viewcontroller, rather than pushing it in a navigation controller i wondered if it was possible to instantiate the view controller to be an overlay on my previous main screen taking up a quarter of the screen, as i dont need it to be a whole separate screen.

It has its own viewcontroller and view, i just need it to overlay at a smaller size.

No code to provide as this is more of a theoretical question

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: no programatic sorry i didnt mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to programmatically add a container in which a second `UIViewController` can be added in in your current `UIViewController`. See the example on how to achieve this.

```
import UIKit

class ParentViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set a yellow background color on the parentViewController
        self.view.backgroundColor = .yellow

        // Create our detailViewController which will be contained in the parent
        let detailViewController = DetailViewController()

        // Add this detailViewController as a child in the current ParentViewController
        addChildViewController(detailViewController)

        // Add the detailViewController view as a subview on the ParentViewController
        view.addSubview(detailViewController.view)

        // Since we dont use IB we disable this property to allow programmatic constraints
        detailViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // We create the constraints for our detailViewControllers view
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            detailViewController.view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            detailViewController.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            detailViewController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            detailViewController.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
            ])
    }
}

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .green

        print("DetailViewController loaded!")
    }

}
```

We have a `ParentViewController` with a simple yellow background. In this controller we add a green `DetailViewController` as a container. The result is:

[image: result]

When you run this app you'll notice that the console prints the result from the `DetailViewController`.

If you want to remove the `DetailViewController`:
     // Call this in your ParentViewController
     let vc = self.childViewControllers.last
            vc?.view.removeFromSuperview()
            vc?.removeFromParentViewController()

Comment: out of interest, how do i remove the overlaid controller when a function in that controller completes, as i cant pop it like i was doing with the nav controller

Comment: what i mean is i want to remove the child from inside the child, so when its function completes it removes its self if possible, otherwise ill have to do a delegate callback to remove from the parent?